# Manually override Geolocation Web to Lead API Value

Tags: api, web2lead, geolocation

We need to manually set/change the API Values of a Geolocation Field being used by web-to-lead.

To populate the Geolocation field the web-to-lead form has the fields added like this

```
GPS Location (Latitude):<input  id="0BC36000000Ztsfd" name="0BC36000000Ztsfd" size="20" type="text" /><br>

GPS Location (Longitude):<input  id="0BC36000000Ztfs" name="0BC36000000Ztfs" size="20" type="text" /><br>
```

We need to be able to override/change the 0BC36000000Ztsfd to a different custom value (0BC48000000Tsdf) How can we change those values on our salesforce instance?

Another option would be to forward the data from a custom value (0BC48000000Tsdf) to these 0BC36000000Ztfs values.

Values have been changed for security.

Would really appreciate help.

Thanks
David

Comment: Can't you change the value from `0BC36000000Ztsfd` to `0BC48000000Tsdf`?

Comment: I can not update the web2lead side as its hard coded into an app that will need to be updated to fix this that will not be possible for a while - so I need to make salesforce capture the data sent to the field with ID 0BC48000000Tsdf and set it in to the field with value 0BC36000000Ztsfd

Answer (score 1):

You could create a workflow rule with a field update so that any leads that came in with (some critera) update GPSLocation field to 0BC48000000Tsdf.

Or you could use a hidden field in your web-to-lead form:

```
<input type=hidden name="Campaign_ID" name="0BC36000000Ztsfd" value="0BC48000000Tsdf">
```

Comment: Would the workflow be able to capture data send to field with id 0BC48000000Tsdf and set the value in to the field with id 0BC36000000Ztsfd?

Comment: Yes it would. Your would create a workflow rule to change the record when it is created. Criteria would be FieldName__c equals 0BC48000000Tsdf You would then assign a new field update to the workflow rule and the field update would simply be FieldName__c value=0BC36000000Ztsfd

Comment: I think you dont understand:
The field ID / field api name = 0BC48000000Tsdf not the value, and our salesoforce instance does not contain a field with that ID / api name. So the value is being sent to a wrong API field and dropped before the lead gets created.

Comment: As far as I know theres nothing you can do with this. If the ID used in the web-to-lead does not exist salesforce just wont accept it. The only option is to update your web-to-lead.